# Frame issues past 250, problems baking new frames

Tags: baking

So I am rendering on Blender, a simple ball hitting a tower of blocks, but when trying to bake the frame limit to 500 instead of the default 250, the animation loops instead of continues. I have freed all the cache, I have re-baked, and nothing is fixing the animation. At this point, I have a looping 250 frame render instead of the 500 frame I was looking for. Any Ideas?[image: frame 250]

[image: frame 251]

[image: bake]

Comment: upload the .blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please show you work in a Blender screen capture in your question.  Show the bake settings.

Comment: @eromod [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5602" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5602/)

Comment: I found that it only loops once, so I set frame 250 as the beginning and baked 750 more frames than needed, but it kinda works now.

Comment: free the bake,then change the ending in the timeline then re-bake [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5603" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5603/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, after changing a force limiter, the bake cache had to be flushed and reloaded. now it's fine.